Issue with NGSSO Redirection After Authentication
When a user clicks on a page link from an email, they are redirected to NGSSO for authentication. However, after successful authentication, instead of being taken to the respective page, they are redirected to the landing page.
The URL link is: https://example.com/1v/app/#!/details/Q10911. However, it seems that the application only considers the part before the hashbang (#!/) and after validation, it redirects to https://example.com/1v/app/
Expected Outcome:
After successful authentication, the user should be redirected to the specific page (https://example.com/1v/app/#!/details/Q10911) instead of the landing page.
Note--
The application is implemented using Angular. From the front end, we are not handling the redirection; PCF is taking care of it.
